# How to store values from a recursive graph function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, recursion

I have the following recursive function - The function works well to print out all the paths of a tree/graph. But trying to add `ROUTES` as a global variable and appending to it results in a bunch of empty nested lists:
`[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [],`...etc

A better solution to using a global variable and a better solution to storing the paths is what I'm looking for and this is my function:

```
 def printAllPathsUtil(self, u, d, visited, path):
        # Mark the current node as visited and store in path
        visited[u] = True
        path.append(u)
        # If current vertex is same as destination, then print
        # current path[]
        if u == d:
            print(path)
            ROUTES.append(path)
        else:
            # If current vertex is not destination
            # Recur for all the vertices adjacent to this vertex
            for i in self.graph[u]:
                if visited[i] == False:
                    self.printAllPathsUtil(i, d, visited, path)
                    # Remove current vertex from path[] and mark it as unvisited

        path.pop()
        visited[u] = False
```

Comment: `ROUTES.append(i for i in path)` Seems to output `[<generator object Graph.printAllPathsUtil.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x03B27F30>, <generator object Graph.printAllPathsUtil.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x03B27F70>, <generator object Graph.printAllPathsUtil.<locals>.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of your problem is that the path variable you are adding to ROUTES is a reference to the same object that you are using to control the traversal.  This same object is added every time you find a destination so, when the process is over (and path is empty again), your ROUTE list contains multiple references to the (now empty) path object.

Your correction `ROUTES.append([i for i in path])` creates a new instance of the path variable to store in the ROUTES list.  That's why it works.

It is a common mistake in Python to store lists in variables assuming that you are holding a copy when in fact it is only a reference and the content may be modified by other parts of the program that change the original.

Note that you could also use `ROUTES.append(path.copy())` or `ROUTES.append(list(path))` or `ROUTES.append([*path])`